# Roman numbering in chapters heading

Tags: formatting, numbering, chapters

Could someone help me with this problem with my document?

Instead of generating the following:

```
% % % %

Chapter 1

Title

% % % %
```

I would like the following text:

```
% % % %

CAPÍTULO I: TITLE

% % % %
```

Please note the capital letters. I'm wondering because my institution have specific guidelines for writing thesis and I'm struggling with that.

Trying by myself I got this

```
I Título

2.1 Sección

2.1.1 Subsección
```

By using this code

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

Which is pretty close to what I need, then I only need, then I only need to add the word "CAPÍTULO" on each heading just before it's number in roman and in capital letter to see like this:

```
CAPÍTULO I: TÍTULO
```

I'm done, I simply wrote the chapter's name on capital letter on the main text and added this code

```
\def\chapter{\cleardoublepage\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{{\raggedright\Large\bfseries CAPÍTULO \thechapter:\space #1\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{{\raggedright\Large\bfseries #1\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}}
```

and tha'ts it, I hope that won't affect too much the rest of the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could take a look to titlesec package and it's documentation if you want to learn about such changes. But sure someone could give you a ready to use answer. (If you could add a MWE it would be a better question : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have working code. If you want an example of how to do this conveniently using the titlesec package, just add

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\huge\bf\uppercase}{CAPÍTULO \thechapter:}{0.5em}{}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: What if I also want to add a blank page after each chapter title page?